# Android, How can I fill data from SQL DB to custom array adapter?

Tags: android, sql, listview

I'm trying to get the data to load into `mArrayAdapter`. Is this at all possible?

I want the list to look just like the other lists in other activities.

```
-------------------------------
Startpage.java,
-------------------------------
package com.example.sqltest;
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Startpage extends ListActivity {
    final Context context = this;
    String[] startpage;
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startpage = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT}; //  <--- This returns the word"content" 


        //startpage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.startpage);  <---- How do I load SQL DATA to here?


        setListAdapter(new mArrayAdapter(this, startpage));
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("this");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("that");
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert("where");
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(

        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent int1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            AndroidSQLite.class);
                    startActivity(int1);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent int2 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            AndroidSQLite.class);
                    startActivity(int2);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent int3 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            AndroidSQLite.class);
                    startActivity(int3 );

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent int4 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            AndroidSQLite.class);
                    startActivity(int4 );

                    break;

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public class mArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public mArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.startpage, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.startpage, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.startpage);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);

            ListView list = getListView();

            list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {                 

                    String s = values[position];

                    System.out.println(s);

                    if (s.equals("this")) {                     
                        Toast.makeText( Startpage.this, getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (s.equals("that")) {
                        Toast.makeText( Startpage.this, getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                    } else if (s.equals("where")) {
                        Toast.makeText( Startpage.this, getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText( Startpage.this, getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }               
                    return true;
                }
            });         

            textView.setText(values[position]);         
            Context context1 = context;
            AssetManager assetManager = context1.getResources().getAssets();
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, (getString(R.string.font1))); 
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            textView.setTypeface(typeface);     
            String s = values[position];

            System.out.println(s);

            if (s.equals("this")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (s.equals("that")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (s.equals("where")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            return rowView;
        }
    }   
}
-------------------------------
SQLiteAdapter.java
-------------------------------
package com.example.sqltest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
        "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;    
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;    
    }

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(String content){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
----------------------------------
startpage.xml   layout
----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="27sp" />
</LinearLayout>
----------------------------------
main.xml layout
----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
----------------------------------
row.xml  layout
----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"/>
```

The code is based [**on a tutorial**](http://android-er.blogspot.ch/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html).

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? What is it that isn't working? Also, you should not be giving each list item its own `OnItemLongClickListener`. You should set an `OnItemLongClickListener` for the `ListView`, just like how you set an `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Trying to load the data in to the array adapter,  this is original: startpage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.startpage); when I change to this startpage = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT}; I only get "Content" to show in the list and not the actual data, I apologize about the OnItemLongClickListener I will fix asap, if I can find a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't updated the data source for the adapter after calling `setListAdapter(new mArrayAdapter(this, startpage));`. All the `mySQLiteAdapter.<foo>` code just modifies the data in your database, you never actually retrieve it again and swap it into your adapter. All you have is a String array with one item, whose values is "content".

Add a method in your mArrayAdapter class:

```
public void setData(String[] newData) {
    values = newData;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // tells the adapter the data has been updated
}
```

Although, you could use a [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and use the `Cursor` you get from querying the database to populate the list. You can look at the ApiDemos sample project in the sdk to see how to use `CursorAdapter`.